# Encode HTML Form POST Data

Tags: php, html, forms, post, encode

What is the best way to encode text posted to a PHP script from an HTML form so that special characters, i.e. "#'@ etc are not modified in anyway. My thoughts were to uuencode the data with JavaScript at form submission and then `base64_decode()` it in PHP, or escape the text with js then `urldecode()` with PHP, or is there another way?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because I was seeing certain special characters in the form data being escaped out for example "it's" appears as "it/'s".

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing them?  And why don't you just decode them in PHP?

Comment: exactly I would need to decode "them", but I don't know how many special characters are being escaped out, thats why I wanted to encode all the data before it was posted. Either way I have found a workaround that I'm happy with. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You do that very easy by setting an appropriate codepage like UTF-8:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/script.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<!-- Form elements go here -->
</form>
```

I would always try do do stuff without client-side scripting first, because of compatibility.

Comment: This does not help, ' is still escaped as \' when I work with the posted text in php, but if I uuencode the txt first and then decode it I see the ' correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but this is what you maybe were looking for:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/script.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<!-- Form elements go here -->
</form>
```

The weird thing is that the enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" should be the default - but something happens when I don't use it.